# add new items to listview in click button

Tags: android, listview

its my codes for get data from server and show them in listview in first load, listview show 10 items and i went when click more button its add 10 new item to list and show 20 items how do it??

its my codes my problem is when click more button its show 10 new item and old item missed how fix it

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

String[] id,name,content,commentcount,purl,views;
String tid,tname,tcontent,tcomment,tpurl,tviews;

private int count;
private int cpage=1;
private double apage;
private String res="";
private ImageView more;
private Bitmap[] img;   

public static String url="http:...";
private ProgressDialog pr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    more=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_next_page);
    new getpost().execute();        

    more.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(cpage==apage){                   
            }else{                  
                cpage++;
                new getpost().execute();                    
            }               
        }
    });       
}    

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long idt) {        
    Intent i=new Intent(Main.this,post.class);
    i.putExtra("id",Integer.parseInt(id[position]));
    startActivity(i);       
}    

private void makearray(int c){

    id=new String[c];
    name=new String[c];
    content=new String[c];
    commentcount=new String[c];
    purl=new String[c];
    views=new String[c];
    img=new Bitmap[c];
    Arrays.fill(name, "");

    Bitmap temp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
    Arrays.fill(img, temp);     
}

/////////////////////////////////get data from server//////////////////////////////
public class getpost extends AsyncTask{     

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pr=ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "wait...");
        more.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);         
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

        try{
            String data=URLEncoder.encode("page","utf8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(cpage+"","utf8");

            URL link=new URL(url+"get_list_post.php");
            URLConnection connect=link.openConnection();                

            //send data
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();               
            String line=null;

            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){                    
                sb.append(line);                    
            }                           

            res=sb.toString();              

            for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
                if(res.charAt(y)=='☻'){
                    count=Integer.parseInt(res.substring(0, y));
                    res=res.substring(y+1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
                if(res.charAt(y)=='☻'){
                    apage=Integer.parseInt(res.substring(0, y));
                    res=res.substring(y+1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            makearray(count);           

            int f=0,c=0;

            for(int i=0;i<res.length();i++){
                if(res.charAt(i)=='☻'){
                    String temp=res.substring(f,i);

                    if(c==0){                           
                        tid=temp;                           
                    }
                    if(c==1){                           
                        tname=temp;                         
                    }
                    if(c==2){                           
                        tcontent=temp;                          
                    }
                    if(c==3){                           
                        tcomment=temp;                          
                    }
                    if(c==4){                           
                        tviews=temp;                            
                    }
                    if(c==5){                           
                        tpurl=temp;                         

                        for(int t=0;t<count;t++){
                            if(name[t].equals("")){
                                id[t]=tid;
                                name[t]=tname;
                                content[t]=tcontent;
                                commentcount[t]=tcomment;
                                purl[t]=tpurl;
                                views[t]=tviews;
                                new getimage(tpurl,t).execute();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        c=-1;
                    }

                    f=i+1;
                    c+=1;
                }
            }               
        }catch(Exception e){                
            res=e.toString();               
        }

        return "";
    }       

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);            

        if(res.substring(0, 2).toString().equals("ja")  || res.substring(0, 2).toString().equals("<b") ){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "conection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pr.dismiss();

        }else{              
            apage= Math.ceil(apage/10);

            pr.dismiss();
            more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            setListAdapter(new IA());               
        }           
    }       
}

public class getimage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    private String url;
    private int p;
    public getimage(String u,int P){

        url=u;
        p=P;
    }       

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bitmap temp=null;   

        try{                
            InputStream in=new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            temp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        }catch(Exception e){            
        }

        return temp;
    }       

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null){
            img[p]=result;
        }
        if(p==0 || p==1 || p==2 || p==3){

            setListAdapter(new IA());
        }           
    }       
}   

///////////////////////////////fill list////////////////////////////////////////
class IA extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public IA() {
        super(Main.this, R.layout.row_main,name);           
    }   

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {                     
        LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row_main, parent,false);

        TextView titr=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_titr);
        TextView matn=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_content);
        TextView extra=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_extra);
        ImageView image=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_image);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsi = image.getLayoutParams();
        paramsi.height= (W/2)-10;
        image.setLayoutParams(paramsi);         

        image.setImageBitmap(img[position]);            
        titr.setTextSize((float)W/30);          
        titr.setText(name[position]);
        matn.setText(Html.fromHtml(content[position]).toString().replace("•", "\n"));
        extra.setText("comments: "+commentcount[position] +"    "+"views:"+views[position]);
        titr.setTypeface(yekan);

        matn.setTypeface(yekan);
        extra.setTypeface(Main.koodak);         

        return (row);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your setListAdapter because its argument is always a new istance of class IA().

You must create your ListView, your Adapter and your ArrayList once at the beginning in onCreate() then set the Adapter once likee this
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
After this you can call each Asynctask or thread you want in order to get new data, adding it to the existing arraylist.
Then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: tnx a lot for thisanswer do you have eny example in this case??

Comment: Something similar which you can adapt to your specific case at https://github.com/alessandroargentieri/CustomListViewExample